# Only a big keyboard shows instead of a login screen (except for breeze theme)

Tags: login, themes

Instead of a login screen I only see a giant brown keyboard. It is still possible to enter a password and login. I can even remove the keyboard with Esc (I think) but only blank screen shows. When I use Breeze as my login screen theme however everything is fine, so it must relate to the theme, but it is broken in any other theme I've tried (e.g., sweet).

I'm using kubuntu 18.04, freshly installed yesterday.

p.s. The title is a bit misleading but I think it might be a helpful description for future users that have the same issue.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: The question is why all login themes but the KDE default fail to work.

Comment: It maybe worth reporting the problem to the developers of the themes that don't work. My understanding is that the Kubuntu developers limit their testing to whatever they supply as part of the distro.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that for all the themes I've tried needed some qtquick modules that are missing. After trying more themes I realized not all are broken.